# how to play .avi file from a remotely connected Ubuntu with -X flag (without dropping quality/resolution of video)?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, ssh, video, video-player

How to open a .avi video from a -X ssh version of an Ubuntu terminal? None of the ones said below work for me:

> The syntax to open any file in its default application is
>
> xdg-open  If you mean play the video in the terminal video,
>   install mplayer (sudo apt-get install mplayer) and run
>
> mplayer -vo caca  It doesn't run directly in the terminal
>   window, but it does display in ASCII characters.

Comment: Is there desktop environment (X server) on the remote machine?